# python telebot. Бесконечно отправляются сообщения

Tags: python, telebot, pillow

Изучаю Python не так давно. Решил сделать небольшого бота, для себя. Хочу добавить функцию добавления текста на фото, но
что-то не работает. При последнем шаге где нужно отправить текст бот начинает бесконечно слать "Это не текст. Введите ТЕКСТ". Вроде register_next_step_handler должно ждать ответа, а не сразу переходить или я чего-то не понимаю? Помогите исправить.

Вот код

```
from telebot import types
import telebot
import configure
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import random

bot = telebot.TeleBot(configure.telegram_bot["token"])


@bot.message_handler(commands = ["start"])
def start(message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    keyboard.add(types.KeyboardButton("✅ Понял, Начать "))
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Вас приветствует бот по имени {configure.telegram_bot['name']} " \
                                        "Жмите на все конопочки " \
                                        "и прочие орудия пыток ",
                                        reply_markup=keyboard
    
    )
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, menu)

def menu(message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
    keyboard.add(
        types.KeyboardButton("текст на картинку"),
        types.KeyboardButton("нечего"),
        types.KeyboardButton("Comming sonn"),
        types.KeyboardButton("сдесь что-то будет"),
        types.KeyboardButton("потом добавлю"),
        types.KeyboardButton("пусто"),
    )
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Вот вам орудя " \
                                            "чем хотите воспользоватся? ",
                                            reply_markup=keyboard
    
    )
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, executor)

def executor(message):
    if (message.text == "текст на картинку"):
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Пришлите картинку на которой хотите написать текст")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, text_on_image_part1)
    else:
        keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        keyboard.add(
        types.KeyboardButton("Вернутся в меню")
        )   
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Такой команды не существует", reply_markup=keyboard)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, menu)

def text_on_image_part1(message):
    if (message.content_type == "photo"):
        file_info = bot.get_file(message.photo[len(message.photo) - 1].file_id)
        downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
        src = 'files/' + file_info.file_path
        with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
            new_file.write(downloaded_file)
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите ваш текст")
        photo = Image.open(src)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, text_on_image_part2(message, photo))
    else:
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "ОТПРАВЬТЕ ОДНО ФОТО!!!")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, text_on_image_part1)

def text_on_image_part2(message, photo):
    if message.content_type == "text":
        draw_photo = ImageDraw.Draw(photo)
        headline = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", size=12 )
        draw_photo.text((random.randint(0, 20),random.randint(0, 20)), message.text, headline)
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, draw_photo)
    else:
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Это не текст. Введите ТЕКСТ")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, text_on_image_part2(message, photo))


bot.enable_save_next_step_handlers(delay=2)

bot.load_next_step_handlers()

bot.polling()
```

в файле configure.py рядом со скриптом записано

```
telegram_bot = {
    "name" : "тут имя бота",
    "token" : "тут токен"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Так вы же сразу вызываете вторую функцию `text_on_image_part2(message, photo)` при задании обработчика. :

```
def text_on_image_part1(message):
    if (message.content_type == "photo"):
        ...
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, text_on_image_part2(message, photo))
```

И во второй функции тоже:

```
def text_on_image_part2(message, photo):
    ...
    else:
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, text_on_image_part2(message, photo))
```

Вот он и входит в рекурсию.

Возможно там надо что-то типа:

```
bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, lambda mesg: text_on_image_part2(mesg, photo))
```

*(извините, в ботах не особо шарю)*